# BackHandler manipulation

Tags: react-native

I am trying to make something a little more advanced in react-native and I could use some help. I have an app with a login and a register and once you are logged and you press back I want to pop up an alert window with 2 buttons(yes/no). As if you want to log out or not.

Here is what I have tried so far. In this version, the alert window opens but the navigation back happens regardless.

```js
BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", () => {
  // Works on both iOS and Android
  Alert.alert(
    'Logout?',
    'Do you wanna log out?',
    [
      { text: 'Yes', onPress: () => { des = true } },
      { text: 'No', onPress: () => { des = null } },
    ],
    { cancelable: false })
  return des
 })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use modal. Set a state to view modal where you can add button and customize the design

```js
BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", () => {
  // Works on both iOS and Android
 this.setState({modal:true})
 })
}
```